# How can I make an object log messages whenever its attributes are accessed?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on a code base with a design that relies heavily on attribute access.  I want to track attribute access for a specific instance.  I was thinking something like this would work:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def get(self, key, default=None):
        print('get: %r' % key)
        return dict.get(self, key, default)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('update: %r %r' % (args, kwargs))
        dict.update(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print('getitem: %r' % key)
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print('setitem: %r %r' % (key, value))
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)


class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = MyDict()

b = Bar()
b.baz = 'boz'  # 1. should print setitem but doesn't
setattr(b, 'foo', 'fum') # 2. same as above
getattr(b, 'foo') # 3. should print getitem but doesn't
b.foo # 4. same as above
b.__dict__['fix'] = 'fox' # 5. successfully prints setitem message
b.__dict__['fix'] # 6. successfully prints getitem message
print(b.__dict__) # Shows {'baz': 'boz', 'foo': 'fum', 'fix': 'fox'}, as expected
```

Can someone explain why the above 1, 2, 3 and 4 do not work as expected? Why does 5 and 6 work?

I thought that attribute access (via b.foo, getattr, and setattr) operates on the underlying **dict** via getitem and setitem, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I don't understand why you expect that 1,2,3 and 4 will print something. You write code for `MyDict` but want it work for `Bar`. They are totally different classes. What is the point? And btw, `__getitem__`/`__setitem__` will only be triggered when you access it like `obj[key]`. If you want to trigger attribute, you should use `__getattr__`/`__setattr__`.

Comment: Further this is not the way to use `__dict__`, you are breaking your class. See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sraw. I've realized that I don't need to override **dict**, I need to override setattr and getattr instead. This works:

```
class Bar:    
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print('setattr: %r %r' % (name, value))
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

b = Bar()
b.baz = 'boz'
setattr(b, 'foo', 'fum')
```

The output is, as expected:

```
setattr: 'baz' 'boz'
setattr: 'foo' 'fum'
```